# WordPress rest api - 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I have a simple route registered in wordpress that will take some arguments

```php
register_rest_route( 
 'myPlugin/v1',
 '/registration',
 array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'callback' => array($this, 'create_new_user'),
  'args' => array(
    'arg1' => array( 'required' => false ),
    'arg2' => array( 
     'required' => true, 
     'sanitize_callback' => function($param){ 
       return sanitize_email($param)
     } 
    )
  )
 )
);
```

my code is like the example, but I have some arguments where I've defined a sanitization callback and almost all arguments are required. I've done some tests, and if I comment the `args` param of the `register_rest_route()` function the endpoint will work without problems. I will get a `400 Bad request` error from axios when I uncomment the aruments and try to pass an ajax call from the vue app I've used as a template page.

The problem will not occur if I use postman. Do I miss something, matbe the sanitization callbacks I'm using or the args declared can be the problem?

Comment: Show us your Axios request then, likely the problem is there. (Sending JSON instead of form/urlencoded, perhaps?)